# Avoid window opening between two screens

Tags: c, winapi

I am writing a Photoshop plugin for Windows and want to place the plugin dialog in the center of the main window.

This is my code:

```
void centre_window(HWND hwnd){
    RECT rs, rd;
    HWND hw = GetParent(hwnd); // GetDesktopWindow();
    if (GetWindowRect(hw, &rs) && GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rd))
        MoveWindow(hwnd,(rs.right + rs.left + rd.left - rd.right) / 2,
                  (rs.bottom + rs.top + rd.top - rd.bottom) / 3,
                  rd.right - rd.left, rd.bottom - rd.top, TRUE);
}
```

So far, it works. But there is one flaw: If the main window is spread across two screens, then my window is between both screens.

I looked at other Photoshop plugins and they handle it like this:

1. Place the window at the main window center
2. If it would be between two screens, choose one of these two and place it at the border of the screen

How can I do that?

Comment: [MonitorFromRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfromrect) gets you an `HMONITOR` you can pass into [GetMonitorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmonitorinfow). With both rectangles at hand you can now call [IntersectRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-intersectrect) to find out whether the designated window rectangle fully lies within the monitor's rectangle. Adjust the rectangle if this is not the case.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you very much for the hint. With MonitorFromRect and GetMonitorInfo, it worked perfectly. But for the adjustment, I used `if (rcPlugin->left < rcMonitor.left) leftAdjust += (rcMonitor.left - rcPlugin->left);` (etc.) instead of IntersectRect, since it was a bit more intuiitive in my opinion

Comment: @IInspectable In case others would like to use my code, I have posted it as answer. Please post your reply as answer too, so I can mark the answer as accepted. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

With the helpful hint of @IInspectable , I wrote following code:

```
void _doMonitorAdjustments(LPRECT rcPlugin) {
    RECT rcMonitorWork;
    HMONITOR hMonitor;
    MONITORINFO grMonitorInfo = { sizeof(grMonitorInfo) };
    int nXAdjust = 0, nYAdjust = 0, nPluginWidth, nPluginHeight, nMonitorWorkWidth, nMonitorWorkHeight;

    hMonitor = MonitorFromRect(rcPlugin, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
    if (hMonitor == NULL) return;

    if (!GetMonitorInfoA(hMonitor, &grMonitorInfo)) return;
    rcMonitorWork = grMonitorInfo.rcWork;

    // Don't let the window exit the left/right borders of the monitor
    nPluginWidth = rcPlugin->right - rcPlugin->left;
    nMonitorWorkWidth = rcMonitorWork.right - rcMonitorWork.left;
    if (nPluginWidth > nMonitorWorkWidth) {
        // Window larger than screen width. Decrease the width!
        rcPlugin->left = rcMonitorWork.left;
        rcPlugin->right = rcMonitorWork.right;
    }
    else if (rcPlugin->left < rcMonitorWork.left) {
        nXAdjust = rcMonitorWork.left - rcPlugin->left;
    }
    else if (rcPlugin->right > rcMonitorWork.right) {
        nXAdjust = rcMonitorWork.right  - rcPlugin->right;
    }

    // Don't let the window exit the top/bottom borders of the monitor
    nPluginHeight = rcPlugin->bottom - rcPlugin->top;
    nMonitorWorkHeight = rcMonitorWork.bottom - rcMonitorWork.top;
    if (nPluginHeight > nMonitorWorkHeight) {
        // Window larger than screen height. Decrease the height!
        rcPlugin->top = rcMonitorWork.top;
        rcPlugin->bottom = rcMonitorWork.bottom;
    }
    else if (rcPlugin->top < rcMonitorWork.top) {
        nYAdjust = rcMonitorWork.top - rcPlugin->top;
    }
    else if (rcPlugin->bottom > rcMonitorWork.bottom) {
        nYAdjust = rcMonitorWork.bottom - rcPlugin->bottom;
    }

    OffsetRect(rcPlugin, nXAdjust, nYAdjust);
}

/*
* Centers a window to the center of its parent form but avoids
* being spread across two screens.
*/
void centre_window(HWND hwnd) {
    RECT rcParent, rcWindowOriginal, rcPlugin;
    HWND hParent;
    
    hParent = GetParent(hwnd);
    if (hParent == NULL) hParent = GetDesktopWindow();

    if (!GetWindowRect(hParent, &rcParent)) return;
    if (!GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rcWindowOriginal)) return;

    rcPlugin.left =
        rcParent.left
        + (rcParent.right - rcParent.left) / 2
        - (rcWindowOriginal.right - rcWindowOriginal.left) / 2;
    rcPlugin.top =
        rcParent.top
        + (rcParent.bottom - rcParent.top) / 2
        - (rcWindowOriginal.bottom - rcWindowOriginal.top) / 2;
    rcPlugin.right =
        rcPlugin.left + rcWindowOriginal.right - rcWindowOriginal.left;
    rcPlugin.bottom =
        rcPlugin.top + rcWindowOriginal.bottom - rcWindowOriginal.top;

    // Avoid that the window is spread across two screens
    _doMonitorAdjustments(&rcPlugin);

    MoveWindow(hwnd,
        rcPlugin.left,
        rcPlugin.top,
        /*width=*/rcPlugin.right - rcPlugin.left,
        /*height=*/rcPlugin.bottom - rcPlugin.top,
        TRUE);
}
```

Comment: You have an issue: if your `rcPlugin` is wider than `rcMonitorWork`, you won't clip it if it is positioned over two screens. You need to compere widths of those rectangles, not their `left` and `right` points.

Comment: Also, your code will be cleaner if you calculate horizontal and vertical adjustments and simply call `OffsetRect()` once. Some cleanup suggestions: `MONITORINFO grMonitorInfo;     memset(&grMonitorInfo, 0, sizeof(grMonitorInfo));    grMonitorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(grMonitorInfo);` is the same as `MONITORINFO grMonitorInfo {sizeof(grMonitorInfo)};`, but way longer

Comment: @VladFeinstein Thank you very much for these suggestions! I fixed them and updated the answer